# Why do Minecraft coordinates change when I copy my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’ve recently decided to find a stronghold on my survival world and I’ve tried it all. Ended eyes and the /locate command have led me nowhere. I’ve read online that stronghold location can change with updates. Since I’m playing on an outdated file, the location had moved. I decided to copy my world to see if I could find it on a newly generated world. The stronghold I found on my new world was exactly where /locate said it would be on my old world, the only problem is that it’s a different place. My question is why do the coordinates change between two worlds that are exact copies of one another and is there a way to find the stronghold in my old world given the coordinates in the new one

Comment: In what way have they `led you nowhere`? Is there just no stronghold there or do you get some kind of error? Or is it literally nowhere, a chunk filled with air?

Comment: Before 1.9 there were only 3 strongholds in the world; afterwards there are 128. If the chunks where a stronghold past 1.9 should exist were generated earlier, that stronghold will be missing.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, when you updated your world, the world generation changed. If your old world was in 1.6.4 or earlier, and you made a copy in 1.7.2 or later, it will generate a different world.

From [minecraft.gamepedia.com](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Seed_(level_generation)):

> Release 1.7.2 redid the world generation entirely, making seeds from 1.2 through 1.6.4 obsolete.

If you want to find strongholds using the old world generation, I would recommmend using [Amidst](https://sourceforge.net/projects/amidst.mirror/), and selecting the version you created the world with in the "Profile Selector". The coordinates of any strongholds shown should be correct.